# I didn't get where I am today without ... or I wouldn't have got where I am today without

Tags: grammaticality

This question arises from a sntence found in a popular grammar book for EFL:

> I didn't get where I am today without ...

or

> I wouldn't have got where I am today without ...

Are both of these used in UK and correct?
The first phrase is in New English File series.

Comment: Which level is it: Intermediate or Upper-Intermediate? Is it practising the conditional tense?

Answer (score 1):

This is a phrase used by successful people when they want to explain that success did not come easily and they had to behave in a certain way to achieve it.

**Typical example**

*I didn't get where I am today without hard work.*

There was a comedy show in the 1970s where the catchphrase of one of the characters was, "*I didn't get where I am today without ...*" The character would end the phrase differently each time.  You can listen to it here and on other youtube videos.  He first says it just after 0:28 (it's said very quickly). After that he says it ***many*** times because the video has been edited especially to highlight that phrase.  I suggest you listen to the whole thing and see if you can get the different endings.

[Reginald Perrin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5Os_SrLJ0w)

The other version, "I wouldn't have got where I am today without ..."  is used in exactly the same way. There is no real difference in meaning.

Comment: I would call it a *catchphrase*, and the character who said those immortal words was Perrin's boss, CJ (if I'm not mistaken). There were other famous catchphrases from that TV series, "Super" was one I remember most.